# ConstraintLayout stick view to wrap_content view

Tags: android-layout, layout, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains, constraintlayout-guideline

I tried to stick `counter` to `nameText` while `counter` should not  exceed the container from the right side.
I want to only use the xml and no programmatically change it.
I played with the layout.xml
code example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="#99776633"
    tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:foreground="#66ff0000"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        tools:text="James BondJameames  " />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/seperator"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/nameText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:foreground="#9900fff0"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="(47)"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/seperator"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**The results:**
With short text:
[image: With short text]

With long text:
[image: With long text]

The **expected result** should be something like that:
[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing the three views into a horizontal chain while shifting the horizontal bias of `nameText` to zero.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="#99776633"
    tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:foreground="#66ff0000"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/counter"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        tools:text="Short text" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/seperator"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/counter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:foreground="#9900fff0"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="(47)"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/seperator"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/nameText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

See the [documentation on chains](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-chain).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="#99776633"
    tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:foreground="#66ff0000"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/seperator"
        tools:text="James BondJameames  " />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/seperator"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/counter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:foreground="#9900fff0"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="(47)"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It's not working with long text for nameText

Comment: try above answer, i have editted it

Comment: But the countrer is not stick to the nameText. It's stick to the right